# Autoformat in NetBeans 8.1 not working for HTML

Tags: html, netbeans, autoformatting

- **Alt + Shift + F** does not auto-format HTML code in my NetBeans 8.1 running on Windows 10. It simply does nothing.
- Nether does right clicking selected code and clicking the 'Format' option.
- Autoformat does work in a JSP file, but neither works on HTML in a JSP file nor on HTML in an HTML file.

Comment: It looks like if I put a tag in a new line then it corrects it's indentation but it does not auto-formats tags in the same line. For example:
`<ul><li><a>link</a></li></ul>` 
remains the same. If the tags were on separate lines, then auto-format only corrects the indentation but doesn't do anything to the tags written in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201510222201)
[image]

Comment: Mine just stays there. Btw, what Netbeans theme and annotation tool do you use?

Comment: Darcula LAF which includes the theme: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62424/darcula-laf-for-netbeans and my capturing tool is http://www.screenpresso.com/

Comment: Mines work NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201511021428) but on another PC installed NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 201511022..) does not work on same file with same formatting and onSave options.